# quarkus.cache.redis.value-type to protobuf values

Tags: java, caching, redis, quarkus

In quarkus, I want to use the redis-based cache. The results are protobuf objects, which can be serialized to `byte[]` or `ByteString`.

I understand that the value type must be serializable, so I tried to use

```
quarkus.cache.redis.value-type=byte[]
```

Then it gives me the error, as `byte[]` is not a class.

I worked around by using `String`, but in the code, I had to firstly convert `byte[]` to String when storing the result into redis, and then get the `byte[]` from String when get it back. This is not idea.

What `quarkus.cache.redis.value-type` should I use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in another quarkus doc about redis, need to implement a codec interface for the class.

https://quarkus.io/guides/redis-reference#custom-codec